# Android Alarm Manager Start time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I have this code, but the Alarm won't start from the beginning of time. I want `myReceiver` to start from the start of minutes and also repeat it from start of times . How can I achieve that?

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent3;
AlarmManager manager =(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


Intent alarmIntent3 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myReceiver.class);
pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, alarmIntent3, 0);


manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME  _WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(),
                1*60*1000, pendingIntent3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use below code to set repeating alarm:**

```
Intent alarmIntent3 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, alarmIntent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Current time
Calendar calendarNotifiedTime = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarNotifiedTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendarNotifiedTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// Set alarm
AlarmManager manager =(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarNotifiedTime.getTimeInMillis(), 1*60*1000, pendingIntent3);
```

Make sure you have declared `myReceiver` BroadcastReceiver in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, but it don't work in beginning of minute. if i start receiver in middle of minutes, it repeat in middle of next minute. what i have to do?

Comment: Just add `calendarNotifiedTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);` and try again. Check my updated answer.